# Receiving and Processing Incoming Emails with PHP

Tags: php, process, forwarding, incoming-mail

I want to setup an environment, where users send an email to mobile numbers with `fix domain name`, for ex. `12345678@somedomain.com` and I will read all the incoming emails coming to my `somedomain.com`.

Now further, I will already have user information with same mobile number, and will forward received email to that user on his specific email address.

Now, what I want to know is:

1] Does anyone know or already have implemented in PHP, `how to check or read / process incoming emails as I get them, may be with SMTP or POP3 or IMAC protocol` and further forward same email to specific users.

2] What should be the standard `server environment` requirement for this. I mean `Windows server` with some pre-installed services or ports opened, or `Linux server` could be a better environment for this functionality.

I tried to search over many protocols like `Procemail, Sendemail` open source resources, however not getting proper help to understand thoroughly.

I see some similar questions, though asking with my specific details and functionality to develop in future. Hope it will be okay.

Earliest response will be appreciated.

Comment: I think this question is way too broad to answer in it's current form.

Comment: @symcbean: yes it is in very details for techees to understand my need, pls suggest if some shortening way in yr mind

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1) You can setup 'catch-all' email for incoming messages so all email will land there. For accesing emails you can use POP3 or IMAP which are supported by PHP: some example: [link](http://www.katcode.com/accessing-pop-emails-in-php-using-imap-library/). SMTP is for sending emails.

To read emails you would have to setup CRON job that periodically checks your master account for new messages - just like any other email client.

2) If you must setup own mail server use Linux with Postfix/Dovecot [great tutorial for Debian](https://workaround.org/ispmail/squeeze) but you can use PHP to just access mailbox and process new emails.

To send emails you can use some library (I've recently used [Zend Mail component](http://framework.zend.com/manual/2.2/en/index.html#zend-mail) and it works great ).